# Installing new software to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have the Indigo version. When I go to Help > Install New Software, the window pops up. I choose the website (download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo). After that nothing happens. At the bottom right of the Eclipse window (not the pop up window) there is a progress bar, and it says "Fetching children of Indigo" and it says 2% and the progress bar keeps on moving. After that nothing happens. No errors, no notifications, no nothing.

Anyone had the same problem before or know how to fix it? Or can I download the updates manually and put them in a specific directory?

**Edit:**

I decided to wait for some time for Eclipse to think, and after 20 minutes of nothing, it gave me this error:

> Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml. Unable to
>   read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml. The server
>   download.eclipse.org failed to respond

Is that the problem on the web-site?

**Edit 2:**
It was the problem with the proxy/firewall configuration of the network I was connected to. It didn't allow downloads through Eclipse. I had to connect to a different network and try it, and it worked.

Comment: When I was using a previous version of RSA (built on Eclipse), this popup was very very long, and result sometimes appeared after 10 minutes !! I've never found the reason.

Comment: I had this just recently. What helped me: download newest version of eclipse from their website and deleting the directory .metadata in the workspace

Comment: Is there anyway I can download them manually and put them into folders? I'm not really sure what goes where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be a network issue. Check if you have the right configuration. This usually happens when your behind a proxy or firewall.

Comment: Where do I check what proxy is used?

Comment: I check it, but I didn't find anything that would help me. The only thing that I was able to change was the Active Provider (Native - Direct - Manual). It was Native initially, and when I changed to Direct or Manual, that 2% that was always there changed to 0%.

Comment: Is your internet access through a proxy or not? If not, you don't want to set anything in Eclipse's proxy configuration. If you are behind a proxy, you need to know exactly how you authenticate to it. Checking your browser's configuration can give you a clue.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with the Kepler version of Eclipse.

I was behind a HTTP proxy.
The problem with my proxy was that it did not allow SOCKS traffic, but only HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

I solved in Eclipse in this way:

- go to Windows > Preferences > General > Network Connections
- select Active Provider: Manual
- fill the Host and Port fields JUST FOR the HTTP and HTTPS Proxy entries; leave them empty for the SOCKS Proxy entry.

My hypothesis is that if I fill the SOCKS row, Eclipse will try SOCKS, which my proxy does not allow, and gets stuck.

Comment: This is a common problem. Open Error log view and you will see something like "System property socksProxy... is set to ... but should not be set"

Answer (score 0):

Same here my network did not allow Socks,

Filling just the Host and Port fields FOR the HTTP and HTTPS Proxy entries; and leaving empty for the SOCKS Proxy entry solved for me,